# How to import 3 different POM.xlm to make them work together

Tags: java, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have a project which is based on 3 different projects, which are connected to each other (one has objects, other two are frameworks with methods). I have issue with connecting them to each other in IntelliJ Community.

In Eclipse it is a simple case - open new project, import maven project, again with 2nd, again with 3rd, cooperating perfectly.

However I cannot find that kind of an option in Intellij. I am trying to open File->New->Module from Existing source it gives me error:

```
Exception in thread “main” java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

it is like those 2 projects cannot see each other.

Comment: Create a Main Maven Project `pom.xml`,  add `   <modules>
        <module>jee-ejb</module>
        <module>jee-web</module>
        <module>jee-ear</module>
    </modules>` , use `File` -> `Open` open main maven project

Comment: `I am trying to open File->New->Module from Existing source it gives me error:` where do you see this error? After what actions?

Comment: After running the code, it seems that there is no connection between those projects. It is the message above.